# automatic change wallpaper automatically by day,night

Tags: debian, mate-desktop, wallpaper

I am having 2 wallpaper and i want to change them day and night. If it day change it to wallpaper1.png or if it night change it to wallpaper2.png. How can i do that? I am running parrot OS 3.8 on Mate desktop enviroment 1.18.0.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy variety`?

Comment: variety:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6.6-1
  Version table:
     0.6.6-1 1001
       1001 http://deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 Packages

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python program [`Variety`](https://peterlevi.com/variety/) to customize your desktop w/ wallpapers, quotations and a clock:

> Variety is an open-source wallpaper changer, downloader, and manager for Linux. It supports a variety of sources for wallpapers, including local files, online services such as Flickr, Wallhaven.cc, NASA Astronomy Picture of the Day, Desktoppr.co, and media RSS feeds (Picasa, deviantART, etc.).

```
$ apt-cache policy variety

variety: Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 0.6.6-1 
Version table: 
0.6.6-1 1001 
1001 deb.parrotsec.org/parrot parrot/main amd64 Packages
```

To install Variety, open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install variety
```

For Non-Debian based OS and further informations refer to [how-to-install](https://peterlevi.com/variety/how-to-install/).

Now in 'Variety Preferences' go to 'General' > 'General' > 'Change wallpaper every' and chose '12 hours'. Then below in 'Images' uncheck all except 'folder' and move both your wallpapers to /usr/share/backgrounds or change their folder path here.